# Google analytics api - bigger date range causes return of less pageviews

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using the Google Analytics API with the Google PHP Client library to retrieve the total pageviews (and other data) of a story on our site - over different time periods. The stories are identified uniquely by a storyId within the url. However, I am running into a strange scenario.  If I use a start date of '7daysAgo', I get a return of around 1000 pageviews total.  However, if I use a start date of '365daysAgo', I get a return of only 65 which does not seem to make sense.  What would be the proper way to get total pageviews for the course of a year? Here is the code I am using

```
$optParams = array();

$metrics = 'ga:pageviews, ga:avgTimeOnPage, ga:uniquePageviews';

//Optional parameters
$optParams['filters']      = 'ga:pagePath=@uniqueStoryId';
$optParams['dimensions']  = 'ga:pagePath';
$optParams['sort']        = '-ga:pageviews';
$optParams['max-results'] = '10000';

return $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profileId,
    '365daysAgo',
    'today',
    $metrics,
$optParams);
```

It seems as though this has to be possible since when Im in Google Analytics website itself, I can simply change the date-range on the interface and use the same story id to get that unique url.  It stays at the ~ 1000 value as opposed to shrinking down the the 65 value.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it's moving to a default date range as 365daysAgo apparently isn't defined - https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS736US736&ei=FYtmWtzBHIyWjQPCnoaYDw&q=site%3Adevelopers.google.com+%22365daysAgo%22&oq=site%3Adevelopers.google.com+%22365daysAgo%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4520.4520.0.4649.1.1.0.0.0.0.52.52.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.euUv3bIIRmU

Comment: If it didn't recognize 365daysAgo, and went to a default, would it still use the ending of 'today'?  If so, then it still doesn't make sense as it would probably be the 7daysAgo or something bigger I would think?  I have also tried using an actual date value like '2017-01-25' for the start value and '2018-01-25' and I again get a smaller subset than if I only go from 7 days ago to today.

Comment: Good point. I'm not experienced in anyway with their API. I just did that search as basic troubleshooting to try and help if possible. I'm eagerly awaiting an answer though, as I plan to start using this API soon, and knowing it's strange behaviors should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if @uniqueStoryId doesnt exist on a day then the data isnt going to return.  You are only going to get rows for days where it exists.

Remove the filter and then see what data you get back by changing your end date.

Comment: If I take out the filter, then I wont get the values I need.  I need only the metrics for all urls containing the value in the filter.

Comment: And thats what you are getting adding the filter.    This is not a relation database this is a multi dimensional database.   If there is no data for one of the values the row will not be returned.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not understanding.  I'm using the same filter if I search for views 7daysAgo or 365daysAgo.  So, when I search 7 days ago with the filter, lets say I had 200 hits Monday, 200 hits Tuesday, 200 hits Wednesday, etc for a total of 1400 for 7 days - for that url with that uniqueStoryId filter on.  Then, I do the same search with the same filter but 365daysAgo - Those first 7 days would still be in that 365 days.  So even if doesn't exist the other 358 days of the year, I should still be getting those seven days it did exist - for a total return of 1400. Not a much smaller #.